# CURL different domain in POST request - PHP

Tags: php, curl, post

Im kinda lost, cause cURL is new thing for me and well..

I am sending few informations to different site - lets call my site site A and site where I am sending informatins with POST method is site B.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.siteB.com/request?form=json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "externalId=" . $externalID . "&name=" . $name . "&surname=" . $surname . "&email=" . $email . "&phone=%2B" . $phone . "&operator=" . $operator . "&street=anon&city=anon&postCode=00000");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $server_output;
```

This curl request send me to page http://siteA.com/some-values/abcdefgh-123456 - its like file_stream, but I want to redirect to http://siteB.com/some-values/abcdefgh-123456.

If I use

```
header('Location: www.siteB.com' . urlencode($server-output));
```

its still the same and doesn't work :(

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: cURL is not used to redirect, it is used to get data from another page (ex if you want to use an API of siteB). If you want a redirection, curl is not the thing to use.

Comment: *This curl request send me to page* - Curl requests don't send you anywhere, you send them. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I can tell you that setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to false and also trying to echo the result of `curl_exec` probably isn't what you want to do though.